# How to use enums in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums

I cant seem to find a straight answer on this say I have this enum

```
public enum DisplayType { Something, Another, More };
```

how can I use this in my angular ts file?

I have tried to do this..

```
import { ... } from '';
import { DisplayType } from '...' 
...

enum DisplayType { Something, Another, More }

@Component({
...

export class ...

constructor(){}

ngOnIt() {
   someFunction(DisplayType.Something).subscribe(() => {});
}
```

this is what the enum looks like in the service

```
export enum DisplayType {
 _0 = 0, 
 _1 = 1, 
 _2 = 2, 
}
```

but that doesnt seem to be working Im getting an error

```
[ts] Argument type of 'DisplayType.Something' is not assignable to paramter of type 'DisplayType'.
enum DisplayType
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have tried to do..

```
const enum DisplayType { Something, Another, More }
```

but Im still getting the same error, I have also tried to do this

```
enum DisplayType { Something, Another, More }

export class...
DisplayType: any = DisplayType;

ngOnIt() {
   someFunction(this.DisplayType.Something).subscribe(() => {});
}
```

which doesnt error but when I hover over it I get `(property) DashboardAlertComponent.DisplayType: any` but shouldnt it say `DisplayType.Something = 1` or something?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I always write `const enum DisplayType { ... }`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @motss Im still getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the same `DisplayType` in `someFunction`?

Comment: How do you define your function `someFunction`?

Comment: @Pengyy It comes from an external service I just didnt put that in for brevitys sake

Comment: @Clint Im not sure what you mean?

Comment: That's your problem, you need to import `DisplayType` from that service, you can't just make your own. There's more to it than just having the same name.

Comment: This error indicates for **mismatching types**, it's necessary to post it's declaration.

Comment: What is the method signature of your `someFunction`?

Comment: @Pengyy Please see updated question

Comment: @Clint please see updated question

Comment: for unnecessary downvoting +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service defines a `DisplayType`, but you also create your own `DisplayType`. Just because these two types have the same name does not make them the same.

Import the `DisplayType` from the service and use that one.

```
import { DisplayType } from 'service.ts';
someFunction(DisplayType._0);
```

If you need to use your own enum, you can pass it as any but make sure the enum values align correctly

```
someFunction(MyDisplayType.Something as any)
```

Comment: sorry as any seems to clear the errors and I get the right number value for the enum name, what does `as any` do?

Comment: @JuvenileSnow using `as any` tells the transpiler that `MyDisplayType.Something` could be any type, and we can't be sure of it so don't do any type checking on it. Use it sparingly, because it kind of defeats the purpose of using typescript.